# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String

Tags: string, kotlin

I am making a data snapshot and i got an error

```
val passwordFromDB = datasnapshot.child(completePhoneNumber).child("password").getValue<String>(String::class.java) as String
if (passwordFromDB.equals(userPassword)) {
    et_Password.error = null
    //get user data from datasnapshot
    val usernameFromDB = datasnapshot.child(completePhoneNumber).child("name").getValue<String>(String::class.java) as String
    val fullnameFromDB = datasnapshot.child(completePhoneNumber).child("fullname").getValue<String>(String::class.java) as String
    val emailFromDB = datasnapshot.child(completePhoneNumber).child("email").getValue<String>(String::class.java) as String
    val phoneFromDB = datasnapshot.child(completePhoneNumber).child("phone").getValue<String>(String::class.java) as String

    //session manager
    val sessionmanager =
            SessionManager(this@LoginActivity) as SessionManager
    // not impacted to user layout
    sessionmanager.createloginSession(
            usernameFromDB,
            fullnameFromDB,
            emailFromDB,
            phoneFromDB,
            passwordFromDB
    )
}
```

error:

> 2020-07-19 09:14:57.129 21850-21850/com.example.configuration
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.configuration, PID: 21850
> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String
> at com.example.configuration.login.LoginActivity$DoLogin$1.onDataChange(LoginActivity.kt:139)

Comment: The string is probably null at line number 139. You've casted that null to String datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the line 3 (of your code). `et_Password.error` is a `Non-nullable String` and thus cannot be set to `null` (as you have done in your code). Try making `et_Password.error` a `Nullable String` by adding a `?` like

```
var error: String? = null
```